# Publishing to NuGet using csProj: How to add Metadata?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-spec

I use Azure DevOps to pack and push my project to NuGet. Here I got two options: Use the .csproj - file as information what to push or use a .nuspec

What I like about the .csproj - approach is that I don't have to care about dependencies when I update them as the csproj is always up-to-date. The nuspec would have to be maintained additionally.

I use the following yaml:

```
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: myProject/O365/myProject.O365.csproj
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: 0
    minorVersion: 9
```

But what about the additional metadata like Author, license- and projecturl which I can store in the nuspec-file.  Can these informations be stored in the csproj, too? So I have accurate Informations when publishing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These metainfos can be stored in the csproj.

Here are a few properties that you can use in a propertyGroup in a csproj -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties